# Java SQL update value while selecting it

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency

I'm currently trying to create a unique game_id for every game that starts. I try to store the current ID in a MySQL-Table `game_id` with a single row `id`. I manually inserted `INERT INTO game_id VALUES (0)`. An easy solution would now be to get the current `id`, set it to the current games id and update the `id` on the mysql-table. This would look somewhat like this:

```java
Statement st = c.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT `id` FROM `game_id` WHERE 1;");
if (!res.next()) {
    st.close();
    return -1;
}
int id = res.getInt("id");
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE `game_id` SET `id`=`id`+1 WHERE 1;");
st.close();
return id;
```

Now what might be a problem is that when another server `server2` gets the `id` before `server1` updated the `id` in the databse they both end up with the exact same id.

So my question is if there exists a way to UPDATE the id in the same query I SELECT it.

Something similar to the following easy way to handle ids in Java:

```java
static int IDS = 0;
int id = IDS++;
```

And if not is there another easy way to store a global ID that every instance of a server can access?

`//EDIT`

A UUID would be perfectly fine if users didn't have to have the possibility to remember the gameId they just played. I want to cast this ID to Base36 later so I could show them the current gameId like `00yq` which would mean the ID was `1250`. A player won't be able to remember a full UUID but a 4 character string is more easy.

Comment: Why update an ID at all? Isn't it used to *identify* something?

Comment: You mentioned _get the current id_, but it isn't clear how your select query is targeting anything, as it has no `WHERE` clause.  What decides what the current `id` is?

Comment: You don't need the `game_ id` table. Make the ID column of your `game` table autoincrementing. This will guarantee unique IDs.

Comment: Well... there is only one column in this table. I could do `WHERE 1;` in the SELECT and the UPDATE clause but this wouldn't change anything. My intention is to store only one single number in the whole table.

Comment: @LutzHorn I know about the autoincrementing function. But as I won't store any data of the game later in the database I don't even know how I would get the newly created `id`

Comment: So you basically ask who to generate unique IDs using MySQL. Why use MySQL for this, use a UUID.

Comment: A UUID would be perfectly fine if users didn't have to have the possibility to remember the gameId they just played. I want to cast this ID to Base36 later so I could show them the current gameId like `00yq` which would mean the ID was 1250. A player won't be able to remember a full UUID but a 4 character string is more easy.

Comment: Extend your table with a second table that holds a UUID. Generate the UUID in Java. Insert it. Select the auto incrementing ID for the UUID. Return it.

Comment: @LutzHorn yea I guess I will do that. If you write an answer I will upvote and chose it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did what @LutzHorn suggested.

```java
UUID u = UUID.randomUUID();
Statement st = MySQL.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `game_info` (`uuid`) VALUES ('" + u.toString() + "'");");
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT `id_int` FROM `game_info` WHERE `uuid`='" + u.toString() + "';");
res.next();
int id = res.getInt("id_int");
```

Aldough it uses more memory than a single Integer value would do it works fine and won't give me any concurrency errors.